# lcd program in rpi device driver not producing any character display

Tags: c, linux, driver, raspberry-pi3

lcd program in rpi device driver not producing any character display. But the LCD is displaying through kernel helper functions such as gpio and that driver program is not shown here. My interest is to communicate through my own driver program also note that blinking of LEDs are working through this driver program but to shorten the program I have deleted that programming code, and even not indicated the user space code also from this code but the driver is compiling and communicating with user space application program without any errors.

**bcm2835_pins.h:**

```
#define BCM2835_PERI_BASE       0x3F000000
#define GPIO_BASE           BCM2835_PERI_BASE + 0x200000

struct bcm2835_peri {
    unsigned long addr_p;
    int mem_fd;
    void *map;
    volatile unsigned int *addr;
};

struct bcm2835_peri gpio = {GPIO_BASE};

#define GPIO_PIN_INPUT(pin) *(gpio.addr + ((pin)/10)) &= ~(7<<(((pin)%10)*3))
#define GPIO_PIN_OUTPUT(pin)    *(gpio.addr + ((pin)/10)) |= (1<<(((pin)%10)*3))
#define SET_GPIO_ALT(pin,a) *(gpio.addr + ((pin)/10)) |= (((a) <= 3?(a)+4:(a)==4?3:2) << (((pin)%10)*3))
#define GPIO_PIN_SET        *(gpio.addr + 7) // after write to mem, set bits which are 1, ignores which are 0
#define GPIO_PIN_CLR        *(gpio.addr + 10) // after write, clear bits which are 1, ignores which are 0
#define GPIO_PIN_READ(pin)  *(gpio.addr + 13) &= (1 << (pin))
```

**char_driver.c:**

```
#include <linux/kernel.h>
#include <linux/module.h>
#include <linux/cdev.h>
#include <linux/kdev_t.h>
#include <linux/fs.h>
#include <linux/uaccess.h>
#include <linux/types.h>
#include <linux/interrupt.h>
#include <linux/ioctl.h>
#include <linux/io.h>
#include <linux/platform_device.h>
#include <linux/delay.h>
#include "bcm2835_pins.h"

#define DRIVER_NAME "bhaskar_driver"
#define DRIVER_CLASS    "bhaskar_class"
#define DEVICE_NAME "bhaskar_device"
#define DEV_MAX_MEM 100

static struct class *cl;
static struct device *device;
static struct cdev my_cdev;
static unsigned int firstminor = 0, count = 1, i = 0;
static dev_t dev;
static int ret;
static char driver_buf[DEV_MAX_MEM];

static int char_open(struct inode *inodep, struct file *filep);
static int char_close(struct inode *inodep, struct file *filep);
static ssize_t char_write(struct file *filep, const char __user *buf, size_t len, loff_t *offset);
static ssize_t char_read(struct file *filep, char __user *buf, size_t len, loff_t *offset);
static loff_t char_llseek(struct file *filep, loff_t offset, int whence);
void lcd_init(void);
void lcd_cmd(unsigned int a);
void lcd_data(unsigned int a);

static struct file_operations fops = {
    .owner  = THIS_MODULE,
    .open   = char_open,
    .release= char_close,
    .write  = char_write,
    .read   = char_read,
    .llseek = char_llseek,
};

void lcd_cmd(unsigned int a)
{
    int i;
    unsigned int b;
    GPIO_PIN_CLR |= 1 << 0; // RW = 0 // directly connectd to rpi ground pin
    b = a & 0xf0;
    b >>= 4;
    GPIO_PIN_CLR |= 1 << 1; // RS = 0
    *(gpio.addr + 7) &= (0xf << 3); // clearning data pins
    //*(gpio.addr + 7) |= (b << 3); // cmd byte higher nibble
    for(i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        if((b >> i) & 1) {
            GPIO_PIN_SET |= 1 << (i+3);
            msleep(50);
        }
        else {
            GPIO_PIN_CLR |= 1 << (i+3);
            msleep(50);
        }
    }
    GPIO_PIN_SET |= 1 << 2; // EN = 1
    msleep(50);
    GPIO_PIN_CLR |= 1 << 2; // EN = 0
    msleep(50);
    b = a & 0x0f;
    *(gpio.addr + 7) &= (0xf << 3); // clearning data pins
    //*(gpio.addr + 7) |= (b << 3); // cmd byte lower nibble
    for(i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        if((b >> i) & 1) {
            GPIO_PIN_SET |= 1 << (i+3);
            msleep(50);
        }
        else {
            GPIO_PIN_CLR |= 1 << (i+3);
            msleep(50);
        }
    }
    GPIO_PIN_SET |= 1 << 2; // EN = 1
    msleep(50);
    GPIO_PIN_CLR |= 1 << 2; // EN = 0
    msleep(50);
}

void lcd_data(unsigned int a)
{
    int i;
    unsigned int b;
    GPIO_PIN_CLR |= 1 << 0; // RW = 0
    b = a & 0xf0;
    b >>= 4;
    GPIO_PIN_SET |= 1 << 1; // RS = 1
    *(gpio.addr + 7) &= (0x0f << 3); // clearning data pins
    //*(gpio.addr + 7) |= (b << 3); // cmd byte higher nibble
    for(i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        if((b >> i) & 1) {
            GPIO_PIN_SET |= 1 << (i+3);
            msleep(50);
        }
        else {
            GPIO_PIN_CLR |= 1 << (i+3);
            msleep(50);
        }
    }
    GPIO_PIN_SET |= 1 << 2; // EN = 1
    msleep(50);
    GPIO_PIN_CLR |= 1 << 2; // EN = 0
    msleep(50);
    b = a & 0x0f;
    *(gpio.addr + 7) &= (0x0f << 3); // clearning data pins
    //*(gpio.addr + 7) |= (b << 3); // cmd byte lower nibble
    for(i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        if((b >> i) & 1) {
            GPIO_PIN_SET |= 1 << (i+3);
            msleep(50);
        }
        else {
            GPIO_PIN_CLR |= 1 << (i+3);
            msleep(50);
        }
    }
    GPIO_PIN_SET |= 1 << 2; // EN = 1
    msleep(50);
    GPIO_PIN_CLR |= 1 << 2; // EN = 0
    msleep(50);
}

static int char_open(struct inode *inodep, struct file *filep)
{
    printk(KERN_INFO "Open function called\n");
    return 0;
}

static int char_close(struct inode *inodep, struct file *filep)
{
    printk(KERN_INFO "Close function called\n");
    return 0;
}

static ssize_t char_write(struct file *filep, const char __user *buf, size_t len, loff_t *offset)
{
    int i,j, k;
    int ret;
    char *temp;
    printk(KERN_INFO "Write function called\n");
    ret = copy_from_user(driver_buf + filep->f_pos, buf, sizeof("Embedded Device"));
    temp = driver_buf;
    lcd_cmd(0x28);
    lcd_cmd(0x01);
    lcd_cmd(0x02);
    lcd_cmd(0x0f);
    lcd_cmd(0x80);
    while(*temp) {
        lcd_data(*temp);
        temp++;
    }
                
    filep->f_pos += len;
    printk(KERN_INFO "return value of copy_from_user():%d\n", ret);
    return len;
}

static ssize_t char_read(struct file *filep, char __user *buf, size_t len, loff_t *offset)
{
    int ret;
    printk(KERN_INFO "Read function called\n");
    ret = copy_to_user(buf, driver_buf + filep->f_pos, sizeof("Embedded Device"));
    filep->f_pos += len;
    printk(KERN_INFO "return value of copy_to_user():%d\n", ret);
    return len;
}

static loff_t char_llseek(struct file *filep, loff_t offset, int whence)
{
    loff_t newpos;
    printk(KERN_INFO "llseek function called\n");
    switch(whence) {
        case SEEK_SET:
            printk(KERN_INFO "llseek called with SEEK_SET option\n");
            newpos = offset;
            break;
        case SEEK_CUR:
            printk(KERN_INFO "llseek called with SEEK_CUR option\n");
            newpos = filep->f_pos + offset;
            break;
        case SEEK_END:
            printk(KERN_INFO "llseek called with SEEK_END option\n");
            newpos = DEV_MAX_MEM + offset;
            break;
    }
    filep->f_pos += offset;
    return newpos;
}

void lcd_init(void)
{
    GPIO_PIN_OUTPUT(0);
    GPIO_PIN_OUTPUT(1);
    GPIO_PIN_OUTPUT(2);
    GPIO_PIN_OUTPUT(3);
    GPIO_PIN_OUTPUT(4);
    GPIO_PIN_OUTPUT(5);
    GPIO_PIN_OUTPUT(6);
    GPIO_PIN_OUTPUT(7);
    GPIO_PIN_OUTPUT(8);
    GPIO_PIN_OUTPUT(9);
    GPIO_PIN_OUTPUT(10);
}

static int __init hello_init(void)
{
    int i, j;
    char str[50] = "Embedded System Device Driver Tutorial";
    if((ret = alloc_chrdev_region(&dev, firstminor, count, DRIVER_NAME)) < 0) {
        printk(KERN_INFO "device number registration failed\n");
        return -1;
    }
    printk(KERN_INFO "static method of device registration shown below but used dynamic\n");
    printk(KERN_INFO "/dev/bhaskar_device c %d %d\n", MAJOR(dev), MINOR(dev));
    printk(KERN_INFO "return value of alloc_chrdev_region():%d\n", ret);
    cdev_init(&my_cdev, &fops);
    if((ret = cdev_add(&my_cdev, dev, count)) < 0) {
        printk(KERN_INFO "cdev structure addition failed\n");
        goto rem_add;
    }
    printk(KERN_INFO "return value of cdev_add():%d\n", ret);
    if((cl = class_create(THIS_MODULE, DRIVER_CLASS)) == NULL) {
        printk(KERN_INFO "driver class registration failed\n");
        goto rem_class;
    }
    printk(KERN_INFO "memory where class structure is stored:%p\n", cl);
    if((device = device_create(cl, NULL, dev, NULL, DEVICE_NAME)) == NULL) {
        printk(KERN_INFO "device file creation failed\n");
        goto rem_device;
    }
    printk(KERN_INFO "memory where device structure is stored:%p\n", device);

    if((gpio.map = ioremap(GPIO_BASE, 1000)) == NULL) {
        printk(KERN_INFO "memory assign failed\n");
        return -1;
    }
    printk(KERN_INFO "which memory location is allocated:%p\n", gpio.map);
    if((gpio.addr = (volatile unsigned int *)gpio.map) == NULL) {
        printk(KERN_INFO "virtual memory assignment failed\n");
        return -1;
    }
    printk(KERN_INFO "virtual memory where gpio is mapped:%p\n", gpio.addr);
    printk(KERN_INFO "gpio pins assignment:\n");
    printk(KERN_INFO "gpio pins 0 through 6 as output pins, pin 0 to lcd R/W, 1 to lcd RS,\
            2 to EN, 3 to 6 connect to lcd data pins D4 to D7\n");
    //*(gpio.addr + 37) |= 2;   // Enabling pull-up control
    //delay(100);   // as per BCM2835 datasheet
    //*(gpio.addr + 38) |= 0xfff;   // Enabling pull-up to the first 12 pins

    lcd_init();
    lcd_cmd(0x28);// 4 bit data lines
    //lcd_cmd(0x38); // 8 bit data lines
    lcd_cmd(0x01);
    lcd_cmd(0x02);
    lcd_cmd(0x0f);
    lcd_cmd(0x80);
    lcd_data('A');
    lcd_data('B');
    lcd_data('C');

    j = 0;
    while(*(str + j)) {
        lcd_data(*(str+j));
        j++;
    }
    printk(KERN_INFO "module loaded successfully\n");
    return 0;

rem_add:
    unregister_chrdev_region(dev, count);
    return -1;

rem_class:
    cdev_del(&my_cdev);
    unregister_chrdev_region(dev, count);
    return -1;

rem_device:
    class_destroy(cl);
    cdev_del(&my_cdev);
    unregister_chrdev_region(dev, count);
    return -1;
}

static void __exit hello_exit(void)
{
    if(gpio.addr) {
    iounmap(gpio.addr);
    }
    device_destroy(cl, dev);
    class_destroy(cl);
    cdev_del(&my_cdev);
    unregister_chrdev_region(dev, count);
    printk(KERN_INFO "module unloaded successfully\n");
}

module_init(hello_init);
module_exit(hello_exit);

MODULE_AUTHOR("bhaskar");
MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");
MODULE_DESCRIPTION("Dummy");
```